# Remove ALL HTML from single page

Tags: themes, html

I want to remove **all** HTML from a page generated by Wordpress.

It needs to be simple plain text, without **any** HTML, at all.

When opening the page in the browser, it should not return any HTML code. Therefore, I do not want to edit a post -- I want to completely remove everything.

I have only found ways to replace the post content. However, I do not want to replace the post content. I want to completely remove the entire HTML of a page.
Starting from `<!DOCTYPE html>` and ending with `</html>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a template for this in your active theme, then assign that page to use the new template file.

### `null-template.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Null
 */
 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
        echo( wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content() ) );
    }
}
```

Then create a new page (or edit the one you want to be HTML-free) and make sure it's using the **Null** template.

[image: Screenshot using the "Null" template]

This should result in a page that has no HTML whatever in it.

### References

- [Template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/)
- [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/) for when you *really* don't want any tags left behind

Comment: Thanks. That already points at the right direction. Almost everything is removed. Now only an `html` tag and a `body` tag are still artificially generated, because the editor forces me to enter text in the frontend editor, which, as I understand it, forces a proper HTML file with a body. Could not get the following solution to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20922186/7061105

Comment: I tried this solution on a local installation, using the block editor and the Twenty Twenty Two theme, and the source of the generated page had no HTML tags at all.

Comment: "the editor forces me to enter text in the frontend editor, which, as I understand it, forces a proper HTML file with a body" No, that's not how any of this works. Are you _actually_ getting an `<html>` tag? Or is the dev tools just showing one? Check the _Network_ tab to see the raw data returned by the server.

Comment: Well, crap. @JacobPeattie is absolutely correct. I just had checked the dev tools. Didn't know, it is unprecise in such a scenario. I `curl`ed the link and it actually works. Thanks to both of you for helping me. This solution works great.

Comment: To future readers: in case anyone wants to change the Content-Type of this page's response, one must append a `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` (or whatever Content-Type is required) after the `<?php` depicted in the answer. For example: `<?php header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`